# Can not install CodeDeploy on EC2 Ubuntu Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am having trouble installing CodeDeploy on my AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance. I am following the below tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-ubuntu.html

I get to step 6 and I do the `sudo ./install auto` and end up with this exception stack:

```
./install:43:in 'initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/codedeploy-agent.update.log (Errno::EACCES)
       from ./install:43:in 'open'
       from ./install:43:in '<main>'
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I have done everything as recommended.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? If Ubuntu 20.04, did you try `sudo ./install auto > /tmp/logfile`?

Comment: @jarmod i did try that as well

Comment: The problem looks like the user has insufficient permissions. You can run `chown -R tmp`. Adding chown for the tmp dir should solve the issue.